# Пунктуационные ошибки в предложениях

Tags: пунктуация

Только по лёгкому румянцу можно было догадаться, что она нервничает и понять, что она не отвечает, чтобы не выдать своего волнения.

Идеи, которые овладевают нашей мыслью, и к которым разум приковывает нашу совесть, часто становятся главным сдерживающим фактором.

Какие пунктуационные ошибки в данных предложениях ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Какие пунктуационные ошибки в данных предложениях?

В первом -- пропущена запятая, закрывающая придаточное "она нервничает":

*Только по лёгкому румянцу **можно было догадаться**, что она нервничает(,) **и понять**, что…*

Во втором -- лишняя запятая между однородными придаточными, соединёнными союзом "и". Правильно:

*Идеи, **которые овладевают** нашей мыслью **и к которым разум приковывает** нашу совесть...*